# $x$ and $y$-intercepts of an absolute value function $f(x)=-3|x-2|-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am to find the $x$ and $y$-intercepts of the function $$f(x)=-3|x-2|-1.$$ The solution is provided in my book as

> $(0, -7)$; no $x$ intercepts.

I cannot see how this was arrived at. I attempted to find the x intercepts and arrived at $2-\frac{1}{3}$ and $2+\frac{1}{3}$

My working:

$-3|x-2|-1=0$

$-3|x-2|=1$

$|x-2|=-\frac{1}{3}$

Then solve for both the negative and positive value of $\frac{1}{3}$:

Positive version:

$x-2=\frac{1}{3}$

$x=2+\frac{1}{3}$

Negative version:

$x-2=-\frac{1}{3}$

$x = 2-\frac{1}{3}$

How can I arrive at "$(0, -7)$; no x intercepts"? Where did I go wrong in my understanding?

Comment: Your book has not provided a problem for you to solve, or you have not written it.  Am I right in assuming that you want to solve for the intercepts of the function?

Comment: You got to a point when absolute value equals to negative real number, which cannot really exist, and therefore there are no x intercepts

Comment: Screen shot from book added above @AndrewChin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$|x-2|=-\frac{1}{3}$$

Two cases:

1) If $x\ge2$, the equation becomes $x-2 = -\frac{1}{3}$, which has no solution.

2) If $x<2$, the equation becomes $-(x-2 )=-\frac{1}{3}$, which has no solution.

Thus, there is no x intercepts. (0,-7) is the y intercept as seen from  $f(0)=-7$.

Comment: Both the equations $x - 2 = -\frac{1}{3}$ and $-(x - 2) = -\frac{1}{3}$ have solutions.  It is the equation $|x - 2| = -\frac{1}{3}$ that has no solution.

Comment: ‘which has no solutions’ refers to either case.

Answer (score 1):

The range of $y=|x|$ is $\{y\,|\,y\in\Bbb R, y\geq 0\}$.  Therefore, 
$$|x-2|=-\frac13$$
has no real solution.

[image]

The curves do not intersect.

Answer (score 1):

For $$x\geq 2$$ we get $$3(x-2)-1=3x-6-1=3x-7$$ .For $$x<2$$ we have $$3(2-x)-1=-3x+5$$

Answer (score 1):

The graph of the function $f(x) = -3|x - 2| - 1$ has vertex $(2, -1)$ and opens downward since the coefficient of $|x - 2|$ is negative.  That tells you that the graph of the function cannot intersect the $x$-axis.

Remember that $|x|$ means the distance of the number $x$ from $0$.  Therefore, $|x - 2|$ means the distance of the number $x - 2$ from $0$.  However, a distance cannot be negative.

To solve for the $x$-intercepts, you set $f(x) = 0$, which yields
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = 0\\
-3|x - 2| - 1 & = 0\\
-3|x - 2| & = 1\\
|x - 2| & = -\frac{1}{3}
\end{align*}
which is impossible since $|x - 2| \geq 0$ for every real number $x$.  Hence, there are no $x$-intercepts.

We know that $f(0) = -3|0 - 2| - 1 = -3|-2| - 1 = -3(2) - 1 = -6 - 1 = -7$.  By symmetry, $f(4) = -7$, as you can check.

[image: inverted_absolute_value_graph]